# Management in case a user's birthday is secret

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing with PHP Facebook SDK.

My application gets a user's birthday. But, if the user sets the status that birthday is secret on Facebook, I would like to program so that an application follows it.

How to get the data that user's birthday is secret or opened?

```
<?php
require("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '(appId)',
    'secret' => '(secret)',
));

$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if($uid){
    try{
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        //error_log($e);
        $uid = null;
    }
}

if($uid){
    $birthday = $user['birthday'];
}else{
    echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'user_birthday');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Facebook API to get the user's age. If the result is empty, assume that the user's has not shared her birthday.

Comment: When I test by my ID, even if birth year is secret, the year has been sent from Facebook. Is there any way of coping with this?

Comment: Maybe you are converting the blank result to a date? Please post your code.

Comment: If you're acting on a user's own behalf you should always be able to retrieve their birthday, if they've provided it - for a user's friends, it's subject to privacy restrictions and may not be available

Comment: I tried to change my birthday profile into private, but 'birthday' parameter is enabled. I think that if scope sets 'user_birthday', it's obtainable irrespective of a privacy setting. I want your opinion.

Comment: That sounds right. However can you set your birthday in Facebook to nothing? Im fairly sure that at least you can set your birthday to just a year without specifying a day or month.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will change a program so that a birthday may not be got.